# Create an Image in Java with Rectangles

Tags: java, image, java-2d

I am new to JAVA 2D, what is the good tutorial to follow to learn from basics to advance level.
I want to draw rectangles having text in it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use JPanel api to achieve this. 
Refer the following sample:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(10/*x*/, 10/*y*/, 80/*width*/, 30/*hight*/);
    g.drawString("TextToDraw", 25/*x*/, 25/*y*/);
  }
}
```